# Is there a way to align title and legend on the same line?

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using Chart.js with Vue to handle graphing data from a database and was wondering if there was any way to get the title and legend of the graph aligned on the same line?

Aligning the legend to 'end' puts it in roughly the correct position, however it is still on the line below the title.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is below:
[image: Graph example]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible without writing a custom plugin for it yourself.
Since its not build to be used this way, the legends box can be as wide as needed if you have a lot of labels. So if you know you will always have 3 labels you can write a custom plugin which draws the Title on the canvas

Answer (score 0):

I found you can set a negative value for `plugins.title.padding.bottom` to achieve this. The legend and title will overlap if the space is needed though. The settings I am using are:

```
plugins.legend.display = true
plugins.legend.align = 'end'
plugins.legend.position = 'top'

plugins.title.display = true
plugins.title.padding.bottom = -27
plugins.title.text = 'My Chart Title'
plugins.title.align = 'start'
```